# Renombrar parte de archivo Bash

Tags: linux, bash, script, shell

gente como les va.

Como puedo hacer para renombrar un listado de archivos, de forma automática, solo modificando la fecha que tiene en el nombre del archivo, por el del dia actual, sin modificar el resto de los valores??

Tengo un archivo que tiene el listado, su contenido seria asi:

```
DASH_20210608175132_0000.msg
DASH_20210608175132_0001.msg
DASH_20210608175132_0002.msg
```

Manualmente seria:

```
mv DASH_20210608175132_0000.msg DASH_`date +"%Y%m%d"`175132_0000.msg
mv DASH_20210608175132_0001.msg DASH_`date +"%Y%m%d"`175132_0001.msg
mv DASH_20210608175132_0002.msg DASH_`date +"%Y%m%d"`175132_0002.msg
mv DASH_20210608175132_0003.msg DASH_`date +"%Y%m%d"`175132_0003.msg
```

de esta forma solo cambio lo que necesito la fecha en la mascara del archivo.

Pero quisiera automatizar este procedimiento, como podria hacer?

Comment: Quizás esto te sirva adaptándolo un poco a tu formato exacto https://stackoverflow.com/a/55951319/2553194

Comment: itera: `for file in *; do mv "$f" ...`. ¿Qué intentaste?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrías separar el nombre de los ficheros con un `cut`:

```
# ls DASH_*.msg | while read f; do
cat ficheros.txt | while read f; do
        echo "Antes: $f"

        d="$(date +'%Y%m%d')"

        f_2="$(echo $f | sed -e "s/_[0-9]\{8\}/_${d}/g")"

        echo "Despues: $f_2"
        # mv $f $f_2
done
```

Las lineas comentadas es porque no sé si vas a leer la lista de un fichero o ejecutarlo con un `ls`. De cualquier forma, siempre puedes pasarle un `while` después con un pipe.

Comment: El número que está despues de la fecha lo estas perdiendo,  en  este caso 175132.

Comment: Creo que te faltó el cut -cN-M de ese pedazo

Comment: Para ser más  específico:  cut -c14-19

Comment: @JuanCarlosGuibovich Cierto! Gracias por verlo! Ya lo he corregido. He cambiado el ```cut``` por un ```sed```